# How to avoid including a page in the browsing history

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I have 2 JSPs:  `page1.jsp` and `page2.jsp`.

the output of `page1.jsp`, under some circunstances, may be:

```
<a href="page2.jsp" id="hiddenlink" style="display:none;" >not displayed</a>
<script>this.location.href=document.getElementById("hiddenlink").href;</script>
```

The reason to do a redirection in this weird way is because there's a layer (a filter) in the webapp that rewrites all link's URLs into unreadable strings. The browser will get something like `<a href="_YerwfwTWEf5YH34njtyRX"...>`.

In these cases, is there a way (a meta or a header or whatever) to avoid `page1.jsp` being stored in the browser's history?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to use [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) via Javascript. Any other method (clicking links, redirects, etc...) will add new entries to the history.

Comment: I'll try that, I wasn't aware of that `replace`method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
this.location.href=document.getElementById("hiddenlink").href;
```

Use this to replace the current page in the browser history so only page2.jsp will be in the history:

```
window.location.replace(document.getElementById("hiddenlink").href);
```

Comment: Should be noted that anyone with JS disabled will still have original page in their History

Comment: If JS is disabled, the redirection used in the question won't work at all.  The client-side redirection mechanism used in the question requires javascript.  Without javascript, the page will be page1.jsp and the history will show that page.

Comment: yes, JS will "be there" for me, so that's not an issue. Thanks for the anwser